# Facebook Mobile Authorization

Tags: php, facebook, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I am trying to make a Facebook Connect web app more "mobile friendly". I am currently able to allow iPhone users to log into the site using the normal Facebook Connect PHP libraries.

Here is the issue:
Using my iPhone I am able to log in successfully. However this leaves 2 Mobile Safari tabs open: the site and the cross domain helper file.

I would really like to avoid multiple tabs, sort of how the Twitter oAuth works. If I have to use multiple tabs am I able to make it automatically close the cross domain helper file? Or at least have it focus the web app as intended?

If possible, example sites that make good use of Facebook Connect would be great also for examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for Facebook Connect for Mobile Web

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_Mobile_Web

Comment: So from what I gather, I just provide links without the FBML javascript?

Comment: The above url doesn't work for me, but these two are live & helpful: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ and   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/